# How do you reference the user_id in a CommCare form?

Tags: commcare

How do you reference the user_id of the user in a form in CommCare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for referencing the user_id is 
`/data/meta/userID`

The syntax for referencing the username is
`/data/meta/username`